# Solr - java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java, linux, solr, jboss, solrj

I'm using **solr 3.6.1** in my project and since yesterday I get following errors if I try to update the index:

```
Socket accept failed: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: 
  NativeFSLock@/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/domain/servers/server-one/lib/apache-solr-3.6.1-
 /example/solr/./data/index/write.lock
```

I already found following "solutions" to avoid these errors (?):

- solrconfig.xml:

  - change index to a compound-index: `<useCompoundFile>true</useCompoundFile>`
  - lower the merge factor: `<mergeFactor>2</mergeFactor>`  --> best value > 2 and < 10 (= default)?
- File Descriptor:

  - e.g. `ulimit -n200000`

What is the best solution?

Comment: Can you check `lsof` output when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

insert following lines to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

Then logout/login or open new session for user You run server with.